# What could be causing my page to scroll to the bottom upon loading?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I have a project i'm working on for my company, and since the project isn't public I can't share the code so that makes this a little difficult. I am using html, css, and javascript. What could be causing the page to load and start at the bottom of the page? I tried checking for any unclosed tags in the html, but was unable to find anything wrong in that aspect.

Right now i'm just fixing the issue by using window.scrollTo(0, 0); , but i still see a brief flash of the screen scrolling to the bottom.

****EDIT****

So after cutting out pieces of my code and refreshing to see what was causing the issue, it has to do with my bootstrap tabs.

I have many areas that look like the code below. If i remove all of active classes from the class="tab-pane active" areas, my site stops scrolling to the bottom, but then this content isn't shown. This particular panel has only one tab, but will get more tabs in the future.

The panels that have more than one tab I can leave the active class on there and they work fine.

Any suggestions on how to make my single tabbed panels show the info without adding the active class?

```
<div class="panel">
    <p class="subtitle">Subtitle</p>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active">
            <a href="#aboutInfo" data-toggle="tab">Info</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content clearfix">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="aboutInfo">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="aboutNavTitle">Page Title</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="aboutNavTitle" type="text" value="About Us">
            </div>
            <label for="summernote1">Text</label>
            <div class="summernote-container">
                <div id="summernote1">
                    ........
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No way to isolate this without something shared here?

Comment: maybe an id hashtag (`#somthing`) in the url? this will open and render the page, then jump to that section

Comment: A quick solution for your single tabbed pane would be to remove the classes "tab-pane active" or comment them out for now at least. As long as you don't have the class "tab-pane", you won't need the "active" class

Comment: @Medard as soon as I take off that tab-pane class the page loads and scrolls to the bottom. If i have that class on, and no active class it loads normally.

Answer (score 3):

It can be something in the url that refers to a anchor

```
www.mydomain.com/page/#anchor
```

> OR

It can be a `autofocus` on an input

```
<input type="text" autofocus/>
```

> OR

A piece of javascript running when the page is loaded

```
window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
```